# QGIS calculate the 3D surface area of a region?

Tags: qgis, 3d, surface

I would like to calculate the true surface area of a region from DEM (2D elevation data).

Is it possible to do this with QGIS?

And if yes, how?

I managed to obtain a 3D visualization of the elevation data using nviz (a GRASS-module) but I do not see any possibility to calculate the 3D surface area.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible. The GRASS module is **r.surf.area**. You can use **OPEN GRASS Tools** (GRASS plugin of QGIS). Its use is very intuitive. For irregular surfaces you have to use a mask.

1) Using the module in the square area (red) of next image:

[image]

2) Results in Output Window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! I tried to use it, however if I clicked on a red square tool nothing happened. So I was not able to select the region of interest as you showed it in a picture. I got the output but it is difficult to interprete since the area of interest was not selected.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you were familiar with GRASS plugin of QGIS. In OPEN GRASS Tools, the last icon is for editting current GRASS region. In this way, I selected the rectangular red edge area for calculating 3D area in my huge dem raster (icon below the hammer is for visualizing or no this region). However, you can use a mask for irregular areas. After, I ran the module with a simple click in Run.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really a great help. I could measure it now.

Comment: What if the area to calculate is not a rectangle but an irregular shape. Is there a way to use a 2D polygon as a mask?

Comment: @AN For yesterday Yes, there is. You can use a 2D polygon as a mask outside GRASS (QGIS Processing Toolbox; clip raster by mask layer) and, afterward, load it in its respective GRASS Mapset of QGIS.