# Calculate or Estimate TRUE AREA from an irregular polygon and a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, area

I have to calculate or estimate the surface area (sq m) considering the elevation data on several places (wich i have in different shapefiles, and some multipolygon shapefiles).

I'm aware of this [QGIS calculate the 3d surface area of a region?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139957/qgis-calculate-the-3d-surface-area-of-a-region) but this is only for rectangular polygons.

I have the shapefiles and the DEM. Working on QGIS 2.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following method would make a reasonable approximation knowing that your raster DEM is a discretization of space.

- Compute the slope of your DEM (this will give you the strongest slope) Raster > Analyses > DEM
- Use the slope to compute the area of each pixel (using the raster calculator , projected_area_of_the_pixel / cos(slope_in_radian) )
- Use zonal statistics to have the sum of the "non projected" area of the pixels in the zone (QGIS geoprocesing tools > raster tools > zonal statistics)

Comment: I´ve tried the method in a known area to see the difference. it over-estimeted the area by more than 30%. that´s too much.

Comment: also have to add that the angle must be transformed to radians, since that´s the angle unit that the Raster Calculator uses.

Comment: maybe you should try smoothing your DEM, because a few pixels with wrong elevation could create slope artefacts which in turn lead to huge overestimation. I now directly mention radian, thanks for pointing this.