# QGIS Rastercalculator: unexpected results for cos() function

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, raster-calculator, slope

I've calculated the slope values of a DEM and created a raster with values from 0 to 51,3 (degree). I wanted to calculate the Cos of these pixel values with the Raster calculator ([to calculate in the next step the total area](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268192/calculate-or-estimate-true-area-from-an-irregular-polygon-and-a-dem-in-qgis)) expecting only positive values (cos(0...90) should be positive) but around 50 percent of the values turned out negative and I can't figure out why.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the coseno function need the data in radians, you can use this:

```
 cos(radians("variable"))
```