# Calculating area of polygon with consideration of slope in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, area, slope

I would like to know if there is an easy/efficient way in which you can calculate the area of a polygon considering the irregular slope underneath the polygon. I would like to know a solution in QGIS.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/139957/2856 https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/268192/2856