# Measuring areas of polygons in shapefile in the terrain

Tags: area

How can I measure the actual areas of polygons in a shapefile in the terrain. Some of the polygons in the file is in flat terrain and some in steeper places. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is "actual area" mean to you?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this tool in case you use [ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm),
and to this tool in case you use [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139957/qgis-calculate-the-3d-surface-area-of-a-region).