# Calculate 3D area with an DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d, slope, surface, shape-area

I have a lot of my projects that are located in mountains. When I draw my polygones, I can easily calculate `$area`, of course. But in many cases, I underestimate the surface of my polygons due to the slope.

My question, is it a simple way, as an expression for example, to calculate `$area` but taking in count the DEM?

Comment: You'd need to get a DEM first. Do you have one?

Comment: Yes, I have one.

Comment: It guess DEM is what OP means by "MNT": modèle numérique de terrain / MNT = DEM. @Stocker Antoine - if I'm right, it would be good to edit your question and replace MNT by DEM as this is an english-language site

Comment: You are right... I modified it!

Comment: Have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/139957/88814

Comment: It is way to complicated... I have more than 300 polygones (and not rectangles) for which I have to calculate "real" area! And secondly, I always have an error with r.surf.area.

Comment: File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 456, in processAlgorithm
self.convertToHtml(self.fileOutputs[outName])
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.8/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 1060, in convertToHtml
lines = f.readlines()

Comment: File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.8\apps\Python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 30: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found myself a quiet good solution, which allowed to handle with a lot of polygones.

First I convert my DEM with the tool from SAGA called "Real surface area". After that, I have a raster with the real surface for each pixels, on band 1.

Than I simply use "zonal statistics" with my polygones layer, to get the 'sum' of band 1... and that's it!

It works perfectly, and it's correct, I tested on different known surfaces!

Comment: A similar solution seems to be GRASS `r.surf.area`, see: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.surf.area.html As it is stated there, "calculation is heavily dependent on data resolution: (...)  the more resolution the more detail, the more area". So this might be something to consider in your case, too.

Comment: As I mentioned, GRASS never workes for me... I always have python error!!!

Comment: And you can't use it to calculate on different polygones!